# Transfinite composition and $\kappa$-categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, higher-category-theory

I wonder whether the following ideas make sense, and whether something in that direction has been written down somewhere; do you know a reference?

The last definition is supposed to be a reformulation of the notion of a class of morphisms in a category being *closed under transfinite composition*, to be found for example in Definition A.1.2.2 of Lurie's book "Higher Topos Theory".

Two related questions are [How would generalizing simplicial sets affect (∞,1)-functors between (∞,1)-categories?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91213/how-would-generalizing-simplicial-sets-affect-infty-1-functors-between-i) and [Ordinal category theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75610/ordinal-category-theory).

Let $\kappa$ be an (infinite) regular cardinal.

**Definition.** Let $\Delta_{<\kappa}$  be the category of non-empty ordinals $< \kappa$, with order-preserving maps as morphisms. We have $\Delta = \Delta_{<\aleph_0}$.

**Definition.** Define a *$\kappa$-simplicial set* to be an object in $\operatorname{Set}_{\Delta_{<\kappa}}$. We identify each $\lambda \in \Delta_{<\kappa}$ with the $\kappa$-simplicial set that it represents.

**Definition.** For $\lambda \in \Delta_{<\kappa}$ with $\{0,1\} \subseteq \lambda$ and $i \in \lambda$, define the $i$-th *horn* $\Lambda^\lambda_i \subseteq \lambda$ of $\lambda$ in the obvious way. We call the horn *inner* if $i$ is neither minimal nor maximal in $\lambda$.

**Definition.** We call a $\kappa$-simplicial set $X$ a $\kappa$-category if every inner horn $\Lambda^\lambda_i \to X$ in $X$, with $\lambda \in \Delta_{<\kappa}$, can be extended to a map $\lambda \to X$, and, furthermore, for every limit ordinal $\lambda \in \Delta_{<\kappa}$, every map $\lambda \to X$ can be extended to a map $\lambda^+ \to X$, where $\lambda^+$ is the successor of $\lambda$. The $\aleph_0$-categories are precisely the $\infty$-categories.

**Definition.** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $\infty$-category which admits all colimits indexed by an ordinal $<\kappa$. By identifying $\lambda \in \Delta_{<\kappa}$ with the simplicial set which is the nerve of the category defined by the (linearly) ordered set $\lambda$, we can canonically regard $\mathcal{C}$ as a $\kappa$-simplicial set. Define $\tilde{\mathcal{C}} \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ to be the $\kappa$-simplicial subset which contains an element $\lambda \to \mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{C}(\lambda)$ if and only if it preserves all colimits indexed by an ordinal $<\kappa$.

**Conjecture.** The $\kappa$-simplicial set $\tilde{\mathcal{C}}$ is a $\kappa$-category.

**Definition.** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $\infty$-category which admits all colimits indexed by an ordinal $<\kappa$, and let $S \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ be a simplicial subset. We say that $S \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ is *closed under $\kappa$-composition* if the inclusion of $\kappa$-simplicial sets $S \cap \tilde{\mathcal{C}} \subseteq \tilde{\mathcal{C}}$ has the right lifting property with respect to all inner horns $\Lambda^\lambda_i \subseteq \lambda \in \Delta_{<\kappa}$ and all $\lambda \subseteq \lambda^+$, with $\lambda$ any limit ordinal in $\Delta_{<\kappa}$.

Comment: What is your motivation?

Comment: I can't give you any specific motivation. Mainly, the idea seems reasonably natural to consider, so I wondered whether it works as it stands, or whether I missed something.

Comment: I came up with the same definition for a really precise motivation: the definition of a cellular class of edges in a $\infty$-category, as part of the theory of factorization systems in a $\infty$-category. Did this thread have a follow-up or further developments?

Comment: Proving the conjecture you mention would in particular prove that the two possible definitions for a transfinite composition agree (and for a $\infty$-category having all colimits implies having all transcomposition)

Comment: @Fosco Loregian No, neither; I haven't thought about those things for quite a while. But I'd nevertheless be interested to hear from you if you have a proof of this conjecture ( - and if (and only if) it's true I'm sure you will be able to prove it).

Comment: for the moment I feel uncomfortable with the definition of transfinite inner horn; in particular the intuition of the horn $\Lambda^n_k$ being $\bigcup_{i\neq k}\text{im}(\partial_i)$ is lost (there are no "faces" in the sense of "maps avoiding a single element").

Comment: @FoscoLoregian I have no idea what you mean. Perhaps you're thinking of a different definition of faces and/or horns, but in the definition that I have in mind, the *faces* of an ordinal $\lambda \in \Delta_\kappa$, with $\lambda \neq \{ 0 \} = 1$, are the images of the "maximal" injections $\alpha \hookrightarrow \lambda$, with $\alpha \in \Delta_\kappa$, that are different from all of $\lambda$ ( - similar to the maximal ideals in a ring). Such a face is uniquely characterized by the element of $\lambda$ that it leaves out, I think. A *horn* then is a union of all except one of the faces.